# How do you monitor the health of the Tridion Services?

Tags: infrastructure, monitoring, network

I am implementing SDL Tridion on a large corporate network. My client wants to see a demo of how they can monitor the availability/health of the Tridion Services. Can anyone tell me what service can be monitored,and if there are any good freeware tools that I can demo this with?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can monitor SDL Tridion services using any monitoring application like WhatsUpGold or Nagios. SDL Tridion has an inbuilt service to monitor the internal functions of Tridion which will then fire SNMP trap (messages) that can be picked up by the above mentioned tools.